# Is it possible to delete all Stack Exchage accounts?

Tags: support, account

I have asked several question on ServerFault.  By mistake I used my personal details including email and company name.  I changed the details after only one day.  Content-copy sites like answerleaks and dev comments have already copied the questions containing the personal details.

Now that is still showing my old company name and email.

I have asked various questions regarding my company's bad policies and bad manager.  I can easily find myself in trouble if someone sees that.

Is there any way out of this?  Is it possible that I can delete all my account questions and start with new account?  Will that delete all my questions?

Comment: Even if your account is deleted from all of SE, I don't see how the external sites would be affected. Lesson learned, don't post anything online you wouldn't want everyone you know to see.

Comment: If you delete your account it doesn't delete all the questions. If you delete all the questions it wont affect the external sites, the Way Back Machine, and certain users can still see deleted content.

Comment: SF is not the place to air your gripes about your company or your manager. The sympathy department is three doors down on the left.

Comment: A good rule of thumb for the interwebs is that if you woudn't say it to their face, don't post it.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably easiest to link you to this question on Meta Stack Overflow which explains the process.

I'm not 100% certain it'll delete all your questions or whether they become owned by the Community user.

> [Can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account)

Comment: This is the correct method. When this happens the devs can make sure that all instances of the key information are purged from all sites. As a SF mod I can do it *for SF*. For the entire SE ecosystem, you'll need an SOIS employee to do the burninating.

Comment: Questions from deleted accounts retain the name of the deleted user, but it doesn't link anywhere; just like question migrated from another site where the user doesn't have a SF account yet.

Comment: The problem is not that data /questions which is on other site . From that one question , one can find my profile in SF . then from there he can my all questions posted where i said bad things about my company , manager etc. so if some how i can delete few questions or i can delete the account but it would make no sense if my username still says same on all questions. If that becomes anonymous then it would be good